# Jersey asynchronous download of a zip file

Tags: java, asynchronous, jersey, jax-rs

I am currently using Jersey 2.13. I want the client to download a zip file from the server, and I want the server to delete the file after the download is completed. Hence, I tried AsyncResponse, so I can register a CompletionCallback in order to know that the download is done. For my current code the client gets: "Failed : HTTP error code : 415".

The server code is:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces({"application/zip"})
public void getResourceTree(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, @PathParam("id") String id) throws IOException{
    asyncResponse.register(new CompletionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Throwable throwable) {

            if (throwable == null) {
                // no throwable - the processing ended successfully
                // (response already written to the client)
                // Delete temporary zip file...
            } else {
                throw new UnexpectedException("The user did not receive the zip file in path:"+ getResourceTreeZipName(id) +" successfully");
            }
        }
    });

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                File file = createZipFile(id);
                asyncResponse.resume(Response.ok((Object) file).build());
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The client code is:

```
private File downloadZipFile(String resourceId){
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource serverWebResource = client.resource(serverURI+"/"+resourceId);
    ClientResponse response = serverWebResource.accept("application/zip").get(ClientResponse.class);
    InputStream in = response.getEntityInputStream();
    //Create and return the zip file from the input stream...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is it that you're using async with [Jersey 1.9](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.9/user-guide.html)

Comment: You are right,  apparently I am using Jersey 2.13

Comment: But you are using the older client API which is not available in 2.13. How is that possible? Are they two different applications? Anyway, I could not reproduce the problem, though I was using the new Client API. Not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: I guess It isn't possible... I resolved some wrong dependencies issues and now the server works fine. I will change the client according to the new API and hopefully it will also be fine, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use other REST tool, for example Postman, and checked if server is returning right object, when it's called by GET with accept header? Second thing i would do is debugging client and check if header accept is set right after object creation.